RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /account/edit/ User has no profile
I can edit other users with no admin status with no issues but this error message saying RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /account/edit/ User has no profile when i try to edit superuser. I created this superuser AFTER I have added Profile module class with its attributes, and making migrations. Spent hours trying to figure it out but couldn't. Thank yall for any help
Models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.conf import settings
class Profile(models.Model):
    print(f'------->{settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL}')
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to="users/%Y/%m/%d/")
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Profile of {self.user.username}'
    

Views.py

from account.models import Profile

@login_required
def Edit(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance= request.user, data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance= request.user.profile,data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return render(request,'account/dashboard.html')
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance= request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance= request.user.profile)
    return render(request, "account/edit.html",{'user_form':user_form})

forms.py
class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name','email']
    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        qs = User.objects.exclude(id=self.instance.id).filter(email=data)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('email already in use')
        else:
            return data
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['date_of_birth','photo']

edit.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <html>
        <p>Please enter correct information bellow to edit</p>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{user_form.as_p}}
            {{profile_form.as_p}}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="save changes" />
        </form>
    </html>
{% endblock %}

admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile
# Register your models here.
@admin.register(Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user','date_of_birth', 'photo']
    raw_id_fields = ['user']


You can handle this by creating a profile object for the superuser if it doesn't already exist by using get_or_create() so:
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from account.models import Profile

@login_required
def Edit(request):
    profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=profile, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html')
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=profile)
    
    return render(request, "account/edit.html", {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})

You need to ensure that every user, including superusers, has a corresponding Profile object. Since you added the Profile model after creating the superuser, existing superusers may not have a profile associated with them.
